# Disable pink highlight in Sublime for BEM nesting in SCSS code

Tags: sass, sublimetext, bem

I recently started learning Sass/SCSS and use Sublime for my text editor. 
Whenever I nest classes with BEM style css it highlights the __selector as wrong code.  Does anyone know a Sublime Package or workaround to not show this?

[image]

Comment: What package are you using to provide the Syntax here? It also doesn't look like it's rendering `clip-path` properly either. In any case, the only way to stop the code from being marked as invalid is to modify the syntax in use or use a different one.

Comment: I currently have SASS, SCSS and SASS Snippets packages for syntaxing

Answer (score 2):

I was able to fix these issues by selecting View>Syntax>SASS>SCSS
This is apparently caused by downloading the original SASS package Sublime.